# Is my front derailleur shifter broken?

Tags: shifter

This is a new problem on the front derailleur shifter that came with the bike. When I do a shifter cable pull, the cage of the front derailleur moves outward as it should (big chainring). I'd expect it to stay in place until I do a shifter cable release, but instead it comes back to its original position (small chainring). For now I don't have the chain installed, but I don't see that this alters the diagnosis of malfunction. Is this typically a broken shifter?

[image]
[image]

Comment: The first thing I would do is look at this question and answer:  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/41966/shifting-problems  It sounds like the factory grease in your shifter has dried out some, which makes the shifter pawl(s) stick instead of snap into the ratchet groves in the shifter like they are supposed to.  This is a VERY COMMON problem, and worth checking into first.  I had a rear shifter have a similar problem and until I cleaned them out (see the answers) I had to snap the shifter a few times to get the pawl to move and the shift to occur. Do NOT disassemble the shifter.

Comment: Wat's the condition of the right-hand shifter for the rear derailleur?   It is unusual for the left/front shifter to wear, because it gets used so much less than the rear derailleur.

Comment: @Criggie the rear shifter was changed once, voiding any comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - the shifter has a series of ratchets inside, with one detent per gear, and possibly some additional detents for trim position.

You pushing the lever over is pulling cable, but the pawl is not dropping into a detent and holding itself there.   Clearly the cable is moving in your housing successfully, so its not rust in the cable.

The most likely cause on an older shifter is hardened grease blocking the detent, with wear being a lower-prob cause.

A quick fix is to blast the internals of the shifter with solvent to knock down the hardened grease.  If that improves shifting for a few months then a teardown may be worth trying, but its fiddly and exact process varies between models.

If you don't intend using the little chainring, it is possible to use the limit screws to force the front derailleur to stay on one chainring.  This is inconvenient if you want to ride up any hills though.